# Partial products of $\prod_2^n((k^2-1)/k^2)$ (maybe)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

I have this series

$$\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k^2-1}{k^2}$$

and I am asked to write an equation describing the partial products. Since I know that this isn't a geometric or an arithmetic sequence, I'm stuck. Can someone help out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry guys, I messed up - it's a product, not a sum. Sorry about that!

Comment: I rolled it back. Your edit was messed up. Try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cleverly get a solution by working as follows:

$$\prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{{k^2} - 1}}{{{k^2}}}}  = \prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{k - 1}}{k}\frac{{k + 1}}{k}}  = \prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{k - 1}}{k}} \prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{k + 1}}{k}}  = \prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{{a_{k - 1}}}}{{{a_k}}}} \prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{{a_{k + 1}}}}{{{a_k}}}} $$

with $a_k=k$

Now use the telescopic rule of products:

$$\prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{{a_{k - 1}}}}{{{a_k}}}}  = \frac{{{a_1}}}{{{a_n}}}$$

$$\prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{{a_{k + 1}}}}{{{a_k}}}}  = \frac{{{a_{n + 1}}}}{{{a_2}}}$$

this gives

$$\prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{{{k^2} - 1}}{{{k^2}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\frac{{n + 1}}{n}$$

so when $n\to \infty$, the answer is

$$\prod\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{{k^2} - 1}}{{{k^2}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}$$

I **really** hope this is what you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the partial sum i.e. $$S_n = \sum_{x=2}^{n} \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2} = \sum_{x=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2} = \sum_{x=1}^{n} \left(1 - \dfrac1{x^2} \right) = n - \sum_{x=1}^{n} \dfrac1{x^2}$$
If you want to compute $S_n$ for a given $n$, then it essentially boils down to computing $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{n} \dfrac1{x^2}$. There is no explicit formula as a function of $n$ which can be evaluated easily for this sum, however that doesn't stop us from computing the sum approximately. The [Euler Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) is usually used to approximately evaluate such sums.

From the Euler Maclaurin summation, you get that $$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = \int_1^{n} f(x)dx - B_1 \left( f(n) + f(1)\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{r} \dfrac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} \left(f^{(2k-1)}(n) - f^{(2k-1)}(1) \right) + R(r)$$ where the remainder $R(r)$ can be bounded as $$\lvert R(r)\rvert \leq \dfrac{2 \zeta(2r)}{(2 \pi)^{2r}} \int_1^{n} \left \lvert f^{2r}(x) \right \rvert dx$$

**EDIT**
If you want the infinite product, then look at $$S_n = \prod_{x=2}^{n} \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2} = \prod_{x=2}^{n} \dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x^2} = \dfrac{1 \times 3}{2^2} \dfrac{2 \times 4}{3^2}\dfrac{3 \times 5}{4^2}\dfrac{4 \times 6}{5^2} \cdots \dfrac{(n-1) \times (n+1)}{n^2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{(n+1)}{n}$$
Hence, $$\prod_{x=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = \dfrac12$$

Comment: Seems the OP now wants an infinite product!

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, the question now is to find a formula for $$\sum_{n=2}^{11}{x^2-1\over x^2}$$ Clearly this is equivalent to finding a formula for $$\sum_{n=2}^{11}{1\over x^2}$$ or more generally $$\sum_{n=2}^Q{1\over x^2}$$ There is no closed-form formula for this sum in terms of the familiar functions of intro calculus (powers, logarithms, exponentials, trig and inverse trig functions, arithmetic operations). There are closed-form formulas involving more advanced functions such as the digamma function, but those functions are essentially just defined to be equal to the sum.

EDIT: OP has no clue what to ask. If it's a product, write out a few terms, and see what cancels. Next time, be a little more careful, please.

Comment: Seems the OP now wants an infinite product!

Comment: Sorry, I messed up - it's a product from 2 to infinity, as in 3/4 * 8/9 * 15/16..., not a sum. Sorry about that!